# eslint Parsing error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

When I use the latest eslint version to create a project, the following error will appear

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

defineProps<{msg: string}>()

const count = ref(0)
```

Parsing error: Unexpected token )eslint

If you modify the code, another error will appear

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
interface Props{
  msg: string
}
defineProps<Props>()
```

Parsing error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved eslint

```js
// eslint.cjs
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
    'standard-with-typescript'
  ],
  overrides: [
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: ['./tsconfig.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue'
  ],
  rules: {
  }
}
```

But when I create a project with a lower version of, there will be no error

The following configuration file will not report an error

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended',
    'standard'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to specify the exact version causing this error and the exact version not having the error. Creating a *runnable* [mcve] (on codesandbox.io or similar) might also help in getting useful answers.

Comment: any updates on this? i'm facing the same problem on `eslint 8.33.0`

Answer (score 1):

The ecmaVersion is not the problem. Just choose an adequate parser. I use "vue-eslint-parser" and have no issues with the interface keyword anymore.

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "standard-with-typescript"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  },
  "plugins": ["vue"],
  "rules": {}
}
```